# Identify min, max columns and transform as relative difference column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe like as given below

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'min_temp' :[38,36,np.nan,38,37,39],'max_temp': [41,39,39,41,43,44],
                'min_hr': [89,87,85,84,82,86],'max_hr': [91,98,np.nan,94,92,96], 'min_sbp':[21,23,25,27,28,29],
                'ethnicity':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],'Gender':['M','F','F','F','F','F']})
```

What I would like to do is

1) Identify all columns that contain `min` and `max`.

2) Find their corresponding pair. ex: `min_temp` and `max_temp` are a pair. Similarly `min_hr` and `max_hr` are a pair

3) Convert these two columns into one column and name it as `rel_temp`. See below for formula

```
rel_temp = (max_temp - min_temp)/min_temp
```

This is what I was trying. Do note that my real data has several thousand records and hundreds of columns like this

```
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a,b : ((b-a)/a)
dfx.apply(myfunc(col for col in dfx.columns))  # didn't know how to apply string contains here
```

I expect my output to be like this. Please note that only `min` and `max` columns have to be transformed. Rest of the columns in dataframe should be left as is.

[image]

Comment: Both the answers below were good. However I can choose only one. Nonetheless both the answers are upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `df1` and `df2` with same columns names with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and `rename`, so then subtract and divide all columns with [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df1 = dfx.filter(like='max').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('max','rel'))
df2 = dfx.filter(like='min').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('min','rel'))

df = df1.sub(df2).div(df2).join(dfx.loc[:, ~dfx.columns.str.contains('min|max')])
print (df)
   rel_temp    rel_hr ethnicity Gender
0  0.078947  0.022472         A      M
1  0.083333  0.126437         B      F
2       NaN       NaN         C      F
3  0.078947  0.119048         D      F
4  0.162162  0.121951         E      F
5  0.128205  0.116279         F      F
```

Comment: How do I know that `max temp` is subtracted from `min_temp` and not from `min_hr`. Is there anyway that I can know that?

Comment: @SSMK - ggod idea, give me a sec.

Comment: @SSMK - I rename columns `rel` columns, so then is possible subtract and divide correctly, because same columnsnames

Comment: I guess something is wrong. It is returning all `NAs`

Comment: @SSMK - Added detail for check columns names, it should starting by `rel_`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204329/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
cols = dfx.columns
con = cols[cols.str.contains('_')]
for i in con.str.split('_').str[-1].unique():
    df = dfx[[x for x in con if i in x]]
    dfx['rel_%s' % i] = (df['max_%s' % i] - df['min_%s' % i]) / df['min_%s' % i]
dfx = dfx.drop(con, axis=1)
print(dfx)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Upvoted. Will try and keep you posted